# Unexpected results when trying to get meta data with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Alright, here's what I'm trying to do. I'm fairly new at Python and I'm only just getting to grips with it. Anyway, with this small tool, I'm trying to extract data from a page. In this instance, I want the user to enter a URL and for it to return

```
<meta content=" % Likes, % Comments - @% on Instagram: “post description []”" name="description" />
```

However, replace `%` with the amount of likes/comments etc that post has.

Here's my full code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

url = "https://www.instagram.com/p/BsOGulcndj-/"
page2 = requests.get(url)
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(page2.content, 'html.parser')
result = soup2.findAll('content', attrs={'content': 'description'})
print (result)
```

But whenever I run it, I'm given `[]`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I used an example image URL @davedwards

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out!. I've updated the main post with the working URL. Still returns the same results, though.

Comment: You might want to change your title; you are not receiving an error, your code is simply outputting what might be called "unexpected" results.

Comment: It should be `findAll('meta', ...)` not `findAll('content', ...)`

Comment: @Barmar That worked. However, it printed the entire page source, rather than the specified `<meta content=" % Likes, % Comments - @% on Instagram: “post description []”" name="description" />`

Comment: I think BS is having trouble parsing that page, it thinks all the `<link>` and `<script>` tags are inside the `<meta>` tags.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to match those tags is with:

```
result = soup2.findAll('meta', content=True, attrs={"name": "description"})
```

However, `html.parser` doesn't parse `<meta>` tags properly. It doesn't realize they're self-closing, so it's including much of the rest of the `<head>` in the result. I changed to

```
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(page2.content, 'html5lib')
```

and then the result of the above search was:

```
[<meta content="46.3m Likes, 2.6m Comments - EGG GANG  (@world_record_egg) on Instagram: “Let’s set a world record together and get the most liked post on Instagram. Beating the current…”" name="description"/>]
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Is there anyway I can print it more "prettier"? Like for example, `% Likes | % Comments % | % Views | %Description` ?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
for tag in soup2.findAll("meta"):
    if tag.get("property", None) == "og:description":
        print(tag.get("content", None))
```

Basically, you're looping over all of the tags in the page and looking for ones where the property is "og:description", which seems to be the Open Graph property you want.

Does that help?

The complete version:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.instagram.com/p/BsOGulcndj-/"
page2 = requests.get(url)
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(page2.content, 'html.parser')
result = soup2.findAll('meta', attrs={'content': 'description'})

for tag in soup2.findAll("meta"):
    if tag.get("property", None) == "og:description":
        print(tag.get("content", None))
```

**Update**: Regarding your question about pretty printing this, there are several ways that can be accomplished. One of those ways involves regular expressions and string interpolation. For example:

```
likes = re.search('(.*)Likes', string).group(1)
comments = re.search(',(.*)Comments', string).group(1)
description = re.search('-(.*)', string).group(1)

print(f"{likes} Likes | {comments} Comments | {description}")
```

But if you have another question regarding this, it should probably be made in a new post.

Comment: This also works, thanks. Is there anyway I can print it more "prettier"? Like for example, `% Likes | % Comments % | % Views | %Description` ?

Comment: Also, if this helps, feel free to upvote the answer and/or accept it. :-)

Comment: Thanks. I get this error, though. `Exception has occurred: NameError
name 'string' is not defined` I've tried using `str` as well. @AndroidNoobie

Comment: Yes, you have to define the string. In this case, it'd be something like `string = tag.get("content", None)` (e.g., what you're currently printing to the console).

Comment: In other words, where you currently have `print(tag.get("content", None)`, try replacing that with `string = tag.get("content", None)`.

Comment: Hey, I've tried that. However, it doesn't work for me. What's wrong with this code?

[https://pastebin.com/rtjTeQd3](https://pastebin.com/rtjTeQd3)

Comment: You're referencing `string` before it's defined. You need to move `likes`, `comments`, and `description` into the `for` loop **after** `string` is defined.